# React only renders embedded app on direct navigation, not when routed to page

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple component that renders an embedded Calendly app:

```
class BookAppointment extends Component {

    render(){      
        const data_url = `https://calendly.com/username?name=${this.props.firstName}%20${this.props.lastName}&email=${this.props.email}`
        return (
            <div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url={data_url} style={{"min-width":"320px","height":"780px"}} />
        );
    }
}
```

However, the Calendly widget only appears if I navigate directly to this route (via typing in the url). If I navigate here via clicking a NavBar link and having my `react-router-dom` route me, it doesn't load. Why might this be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I previously put the script file in the `<head>` of my `index.html` file. Unfortunately, to solve this, I had to modify the DOM directly, appending and removing the widget dynamically when the component mounted and unmounted:

```
.
.
.
    componentDidMount() {
        const head = document.querySelector('head');
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.id = "calendly-widget";
        script.setAttribute('src',  'https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js');
        head.appendChild(script);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        const calendlyWidget = document.getElementById("calendly-widget");
        const head = document.querySelector("head");
        head.removeChild(calendlyWidget);
    }
```

I'm not really sure about why I had to do this. If anyone could comment with the reason, I think that would enhance the quality of this answer for others.